# Quarterly Data - Convert Factor to Date

Tags: r, date, lubridate, posixct

Unable to convert date column from factor to date type. I've tried base r and lubridate strategies:

```
> as.Date(df)
Error in as.Date.default(x, ...) : 
  do not know how to convert 'x' to class “Date”

> yq(df)
[1] NA
Warning message:
All formats failed to parse. No formats found.
```

Data:

```
df<- structure(list(Date = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("2008-07-31", 
"2009-07-31", "2010-07-31", "2011-07-31", "2012-07-31", "2013-07-31", 
"2014-07-31", "2011-10-31", "2012-10-31", "2013-10-31", "2014-10-31", 
"2016-10-31", "2017-10-31"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply `as.Date` to the `Date` column, not the entire data.frame.  No packages are used.

```
transform(df, Date = as.Date(Date))
```

giving:

```
        Date
1 2008-07-31
2 2008-07-31
3 2008-07-31
4 2008-07-31
5 2008-07-31
6 2008-07-31
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer above showed the base R approach to your question. I have used the `tidyverse` packages to do the same thing, just as a different way of doing things.

First of all, we will have a look at your data

```
df<- structure(list(Date = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("2008-07-31", 
"2009-07-31", "2010-07-31", "2011-07-31", "2012-07-31", "2013-07-31", 
"2014-07-31", "2011-10-31", "2012-10-31", "2013-10-31", "2014-10-31", 
"2016-10-31", "2017-10-31"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")

print(df)

        Date
1 2008-07-31
2 2008-07-31
3 2008-07-31
4 2008-07-31
5 2008-07-31
6 2008-07-31
```

If we have a look at the structure of the data frame, we can see the dates are stored as factors

```
str(df)

'data.frame':   6 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ Date: Factor w/ 13 levels "2008-07-31","2009-07-31",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

We need to load some libraries. The only one requiring explanation is the `magrittr` package which provides the handy `%<>%` operator, which assigns the results of the operations on the right side of the pipeline to the original variable

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(magrittr)
```

So in the pipeline below, we -

- pipe the `df` data frame of dates as factors through `as_tibble()` which converts it to the tidyverse tibble format
- then use the `mutate` function to overwrite the `Date` column,
- replacing its value with the results of the `lubridate` function `ymd`, which is a convenience function that parses dates in factor or string formats in a `year-month-date` structure. An equivalent might be `dmy` if the data is in `day-month-year` format.

```
df %<>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  mutate(
    Date = ymd(Date)
  )
```

Now that is done, we can look at the data

```
print(df)
# A tibble: 6 x 1
  Date      
  <date>    
1 2008-07-31
2 2008-07-31
3 2008-07-31
4 2008-07-31
5 2008-07-31
6 2008-07-31
```

You can now see that the dates are now stored as the `date` data type.

Final comment -

If you want to do manual creation of data tables or `tibbles`, have a look at the `tribble` function as follows, where we manually create the same tibble as you did, then cast the data type to `factor`

```
df <- tribble(
    ~Date,
    "2008-07-31", 
    "2009-07-31", 
    "2010-07-31", 
    "2011-07-31", 
    "2012-07-31", 
    "2013-07-31", 
    "2014-07-31", 
    "2011-10-31", 
    "2012-10-31", 
    "2013-10-31", 
    "2014-10-31", 
    "2016-10-31", 
    "2017-10-31") 


df %<>%
  mutate(
    Date = as_factor(Date)
  )

glimpse(df)

Observations: 13
Variables: 1
$ Date <fct> 2008-07-31, 2009-07-31, 2010-07-31, 2011-07-31, 2012-07-31, 2013-07-31, 2014-07-31, 2011-10-31, 2012-10-31, 2013-10-31, 2014-10-31...
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by showing _why_ this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Comment: Revised, as suggested. Thanks.